# Php select from two tables not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

Hello everyone i have two tables

seo_settings

```
| cat_id | cat_fullname | 
| 971    | catname 1    |
| 443    | catname 2    |
```

jcategories_to_hcategories

```
| jcategory_id | hcategory_id |
| 1            | 971          |
| 2            | 443          |
| 3            | 443          |
```

and i want get cat_fullname by category id

I am using this

```
$catIds = array(1,2,3)

foreach($catIds as $catId)
{
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT a.cat_fullname FROM seo_settings a, jcategories_to_hcategories b  WHERE a.cat_id = b.hcategory_id AND b.jcategory_id = $catId ");
    $data3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3);
}
```

but $data3 return booleanfalse

IMPORTANT there are rows and they are connected correctly I assume there is a problem in my sql probably.

Comment: could you please execute the same query in mysql and see what happens ? And also try using explicit JOIN instead of implicit.

Comment: Since your code is in mysql , I'm suggessting this. Use `mysql_error()` function to check what error you are getting. Avoid using `mysqll_*` and use `mysqli_*`

Comment: `...FROM seo_settings AS a, jcategories_to_hcategories AS b...`

Comment: i used or die to use mysql error and it does not return any errors also i used dirrectly a number instead of variable and i worked in database it is integer and when i var dumped my catId variable it is integer too .. so it is ot type problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$catIds = array(1,2,3);

$query = "
SELECT a.cat_fullname 
FROM seo_settings AS a 
LEFT JOIN jcategories_to_hcategories AS b ON jcategories_to_hcategories b 
WHERE b.jcategory_id IN (".implode(",", $catIds).")
";
$sql3 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($data3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3))
{
    echo $data3['cat_fullname'].'<br>';
}
```

side note: stop using mysql_ and switch to mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: our mysql still runs on old version :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listing the two tables with ', ' you need to use an inner join.  Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT a.cat_fullname
FROM seo_settings a
INNER JOIN jcategories_to_hcategories b
    WHERE a.cat_id = b.hcategory_id
    AND b.jcategory_id = $catId
```